# Microsoft Analysis Service (SSAS) - Unable to create a database

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012

Create DB is failing with the below error for SSAS
OS - Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Datacenter

```
===================================

Internal error: An unexpected error occurred (file 'pcserialize.cpp', line 1535, function 'ASDatabase::Serialize').
 (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.Alter(IMajorObject obj, ObjectExpansion expansion, ImpactDetailCollection impact, Boolean allowCreate, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, JaXmlSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Update(IMajorObject obj, UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.SendUpdate(IMajorObject obj, UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject.Update(UpdateOptions options, UpdateMode mode, XmlaWarningCollection warnings)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject.Update(UpdateOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs.OlapCreateDB.SendDataToServer()
```

Any pointers if I am missing something?

Create a test database

Comment: How are you creating the database?

Comment: I am connected to Analysis service via sql server management studio . Right clicking on the analysis service --> Create New database

Comment: That’s an unusual way to create a database.  Have you tried deploying a Visual Studio project?